# UWP Webview 2 WebViewContainer.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript without C++ WinRT Component

Tags: uwp, webview2, c++-winrt

I have a UWP application where I am using WebView 2 Controls to host the websites.

Now when I need to connect between Js and my C# code all are saying to use the WinRT C++ adapter wrapper.

> var dispatchAdapter = new WinRTAdapter.DispatchAdapter(); WebViewContainer.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("external", dispatchAdapter.WrapObject(App.MessageCallWrapper, dispatchAdapter));

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/winrt-from-js?tabs=winui2%2Cwinrtcsharp

Is is necessary to use the WinRT C++ adapter project in UWP, without that I get error every-time and using it I am able to access the C# class from JS script.

Thanks,

Vishy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/winrt-from-js?tabs=winui2%2Cwinrtcsharp

POC worked with C++ winrt adapter, but need without that adapter

Comment: This is from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/winrt-from-js?tabs=winui2%2Cwinrtcsharp) you supplied: *"For .NET use of `AddHostObjectToScript`, see [Call native-side code from web-side code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/hostobject) instead of this article."* Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the C++/WinRT DispatchAdapter project in your solution. This project contains and builds the wv2winrt generated code. wv2winrt takes metadata about the WinRT classes you want to use in script (via the .winmd files) and generates C++/WinRT wrapper code that can interact with `CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript`. You can keep the C++/WinRT code in its own project and because it produces WinRT classes, you can use it from your application project that does not have to be written in the same language. Your application project can be written in any WinRT supported language.

In your case your application can be written in C# and the DispatchAdapter project is in C++.

Comment: Is it going to create any issue in the field, coz we wont have much knowledge on C++ code and cant debug it tooo??

Point is how is the C++ code generated is reliable???

Comment: Is there any alternative for this instead of winrt C++ adapter?

Comment: There is no alternative when using C# objects with the WinRT WebView2 API. You could use PostWebMessage and chrome.webview.postMessage to communicate with strings between the host app and the JS to avoid using AddHostObjectToScript.